# Windows 10 is corrupting UEFI Ubuntu grub boot entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Background:

```
Dual boot system, with Ubuntu 20.4.4 and Windows 10
Motherboard: Tomahawk B450 Max
Storage:     NVME 1TB ssd - split between Ubuntu and Windows
CPU:         AMD Ryzen 3600
Memory:      16GB
```

I've been using this dual boot system for over a year.
I recently updated the BIOS, which caused reinitialized the "boot order" settings, eliminating the "ubuntu" entry, causing it to boot straight into Windows.  grub was no where to be found.

To fix it I first ran "boot-repair" from a Live session, and rebooted.
Straight into windows, without seeing grub.

Next I ran this from windows:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

At start of the reboot, after the screen was cleared I got a message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\yyyy - Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image \EFI\UBUNTU\yyyy: Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter, falling back to default loader
```

Note: yyyy - consists of two reverse-video question marks, followed by two
asian characters, an S, followed by "soh"

Next that screen disappeared and Grub screen appeared.... and worked.

Further research indicates (according efibootmgr) that the boot manager's entry for Ubuntu is modified after booting via Grub into windows.  Here is a file I created invoking "efibootmgr -v" in the following times:

1. After booting via grub into Ubuntu
2. After rebooting, and starting an Ubuntu live session, running boot-repair, then booting via grub into Ubuntu
3. After rebooting, and booting via grub into Window10, then rebooting from windows, booting via grub into Ubuntu

Please notice the "Boot0000*" line on each of the three different times efibootmgr was run, notice the end differs ...
The second one ends: "/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO"  Which is the expected ending.
The other two ends:  "/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)WINDOWS...." extending much further.

Here is the contents of my file, with annotations to identify when each efibootmgr invocation was made:

```
Before running boot-repair:

:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
[sudo] password for trb:
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO

After running boot-repair on a Live-Session at 05:52 05/20/2022, 
then immediately booting via grub into Ubuntu:

:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
[sudo] password for trb:
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO

After rebooting, and booting via grub into Windows 10:

:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
[sudo] password for trb:
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,6f5b61c0-cf1c-4414-bc56-4cb4de62b22d,0x109000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)..BO
```

Here is a link to the corrections that boot-repair made the last time
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PXhpZRtKsm/

Comment: Not seeing issue now? My old Asus after UEFI update needed 7 settings redone. I had to keep a list. A Windows update will reset boot order to have Windows first. Did system also have an update to Windows? Similar to a major update to grub/shim resets boot order to ubuntu entry first, even for those who want Windows first. If efibootmgr does not now the invalid chars, so is it ok? If still there, delete entry & create new to see if that resolves issue.

Comment: @oldfred:  I continue getting the "failed to load image..." boot-time messages, but otherwise it is working.  I can rid myself of that "failed to load image" message, and it will stay gone by running a live-session and running boot-repair... as long as I never boot into Windows.  But Once I boot into Windows, the "failed to load image" message resumes, and efibootmgr reports the "long" version of Boot0000 entry.  So, your suggestion is that I use efibootmgr to delete Boot0000 entry, and then use boot-repair to put the entry back into the UEFI Boot Manager table..??

Comment: Not sure if then UEFI or WIndows issue. UEFI may error out on a boot entry and then load another default. You should not be getting corrupted entry, but do not know a solution. Either remove BCD edit and/or change to use shimx64.efi as tests?